# I don't get the results I want from my query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables called 'District' and 'SensorData'. From these two tables I want to know which points from table 'SensorData' are inside 'District' polygons.

I have written this query to get the results I want:

```
SELECT combined_sensor_data.point_geom, district.geom_pol
FROM combined_sensor_data, district
WHERE ST_Within(district.geom_pol, combined_sensor_data.point_geom);
```

but unfortunately I get no point in any district. Which I know for sure that this is a wrong result. So I am assuming I have a mistake in my query. Therefore, I am asking what could be wrong in my query?

Comment: Please show a small amount of data associated with the query - that will make it easier for others to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing arguments order:

```
SELECT combined_sensor_data.point_geom, district.geom_pol
FROM combined_sensor_data
JOIN district
  ON ST_Within(combined_sensor_data.point_geom, district.geom_pol);
```

Comment: thanks Lukasz, but it didn't work either. I suspect the problem then might be something else which I have no idea what could it be :(

Comment: all of the solutions worked, but the problem was somewhere else, anyways thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, it seems you want to check if the table2 ('District') also has the same data points as in table1 ('Sensor Data').

You can use the PostgreSQL EXISTS for this:

```
select combined_sensor_data.point_geom from combined_sensor_data sd 
where exists (select 1 from district d where d.geom_pol=sd.point_geom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It changes whether the point is contained by any of the polygon in other table or is overlaped on the polygon. you might need to change the group by clause

```
SELECT combined_sensor_data.point_geom, district.geom_pol
            bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom_pol, T1.point_geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.point_geom,T2.geom_pol))) AS my_bool
            FROM combined_sensor_data AS T1
                CROSS JOIN district AS T2 WHERE my_bool is true
                GROUP BY combined_sensor_data.point_geom, district.geom_pol
```